# Using python class to access MySQL but Internal Server Error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Here is the class I used to connect and query the data I wanted.

```
class DatabaseOperations():
# Fill in the information of your database server.
__db_url = 'localhost'
__db_username = 'root'
__db_password = ''
__db_name = 'dates'
__db = ''
def __init__(self):
    self.__db = self.db_connect()

def __del__(self):
    """Disconnect from database when the object is destroyed."""
    self.__db.close()
def db_connect(self):
    self.__db = pymysql.connect(self.__db_url, self.__db_username,
    self.__db_password, self.__db_name)
    return self.__db
def query_events_by_date(self, date):
    cursor = self.__db.cursor()
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    sql = "select event_name from events,dates,dates_events where events.event_id = dates_events.event_id AND dates.data_id = dates_events.data_id AND dates.data = '%s'"%(data)
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    except:
        print("Error: unable to fetch data")
    return results
```

and the code above is that allows the user to input a date and query the events of the given date from the database.

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def query():
   #events=["inoput in right"]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        events = data
        do = DatabaseOperations()
        result = do.query_events_by_date(data)
        events = []
        for i in result:
            events.append(i[1])
        del db # close the database
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Assign the variables, convert to string.3
    time = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return render_template('query.html', events=events, date = time)
```

but it always shows
"Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error" and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
If I remove the "result = do.query_events_by_date(data)", the error will disappear.
I want to know the reason and how to fix it.

terminal

```
PS C:\Users\Dongsheng\Desktop\code> $env:FLASK_APP = "application.py"
PS C:\Users\Dongsheng\Desktop\code> flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application.py"
```

* Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2020 23:01:35] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
[2020-05-03 23:01:38,360] ERROR in app: Exception on /query [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\dongsheng\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Dongsheng\Desktop\code\application.py", line 98, in query
    return render_template('query.html', events=events, date = time)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'events' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: sorry, it's my first time asking question on online. Should I add more?

Comment: basically you define def query(): and only have code  for POST but you call it wth GET where only the non indented code runs and causes problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix is this 
Place `events` on top of the if conditional this way the events list is created and filled up in the POST condition

Also your method doesn't seem to be indented